# Finding the set of values of a parameter $a$ given in the inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Find the set of values of a for which $(a-1)x^2 - (a+1)x +a-1\ge 0$ is
>   true for all $x\ge 2$

There are two constraints for the condition to be satisfied:

1. $a-1>0 \implies a>1$
2. $\Delta\le0$ which yields $a\in(-\infty,1/3]\cup[3,\infty)$

But I am unable to understand how to use the condition $x\ge2$. Can someone guide me on that?

PS: Answer is: $[7/3,\infty)$

Comment: $\Delta\le0$ will guarantee that the inequality is true for **all** values of $x$, which is too much.

Comment: If you were to graph the LHS you'd only consider the part of the graph including and to the right of $x=2$. So if for a particular value of $a$, the value of the LHS was $<0$ for $x=1$, you wouldn't care about that because $x$ would be $<2$. If you set LHS equal to zero, and solve for $a$ with $x=2$ you'll find the one value of $a$ where expression is zero for $x=2$. If you then show that the LHS doesn't decrease for $x$ increasing above 2, then you've found the value of $a$ that was asked for.  **BTW, what is $\Delta$?**

Comment: @Χpẘ $\Delta$ denotes discriminant

Comment: @Abcd. Ok thanks. $\Delta = a^2+2a+1-4a^2+8a-4=-3a^2+10a-3$. This gives the range for $a$ in #2 in OP. However that contradicts the solution being $[7/3,\infty)$. $\Delta \leq 4$ corresponds to $a \geq 7/3$

Answer (score 2):

The constraint $x \ge 2$ is used to figure out a constraint on $a$. In particular, for $x=2$, $$(a-1)x^2-(a+1)x+(a-1) \ge 0 \implies a \ge 7/3.$$

Further, the minimum of $\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma$ occurs at $x = -\beta/(2\alpha)$ when $\alpha > 0$. In your case, $$-\frac{\beta}{2\alpha}=\frac{a+1}{2(a-1)} \le 2 \implies a\ge 5/3.$$
Consequently, the minimum of $(a-1)x^2-(a+1)x+(a-1)$ occurs before $x=2$ for $a \ge 7/3$, which implies the function increases monotonically for $x\ge 2$. As such, $\color{blue}{a \ge 7/3}$ implies $(a-1)x^2-(a+1)x+(a-1) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 2$.